# jQuery does not works when exporting html table to excel

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have HTML table that i want to export as excel , that works!

I needed to show total value of one column on top of the page (and it works on browser) i did it with jQuery.

Here is were i add total value:

```
echo '<p style="display:inline-block;" class="total-title"></p>';
```

Here is how i add value:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('p.total-title').html('&nbsp;total: <?=$total;?>');
    }
);
</script>
```

And here are my headers:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=print_report(".date('Y-m-d').").xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');  
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

All other data is exported but just this jQuery added content is not showing!

Why it works when i remove headers? And why could it not work in export?

What possible fixes are here?

Thanks

Comment: Of course not. That function gets executed by the browser. Excel knows nothing about jQuery.

Comment: Also, I hope that you're not really doing this but it was just for the sake of a minimal example here.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca But i create content and only then export it doesnt i? And whats wrong if i do? Please explain me

Comment: That piece of jQuery never reaches the browser. It's php that's generating the file and instructing the browser to not treat it like a page. That means that one the file is `echo`ed, it needs to be in its final form, ready to be opened by excel.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca so that means jQuery on export cant change anything if html already echo ed?

Comment: Exactly. In this particular case the solution would be to just do `echo sprintf('<p style="display:inline-block;" class="total-title">%s</p>', $total);` directly with php.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i did like this cuz i could not get value on top just with php

Comment: @ingus-graholskis     you create a export excel on button click with jquery of HTML table then use the total price on the top of table.

Comment: This seems weird, since you're outputting the paragraph *and* the piece of javascript containing the `$total` variable.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i m not that big expert yet in PHP but what i do is  $total += $rowValue and then i did put $total in javascript . I just could not find the proper way to be able to use that variable on top!

Comment: @ingus-graholskis you have table of data which  generates dynamically , then add code for $total where u want & then export it.

Comment: @MohitKumar but PHP works in order from top right? If $total is made in bottom of page how can i show it on top?

Comment: @IngusGraholskis first you do your calculations, when you're done you start printing your totals and your table. It's not a php thing, it's a basic pattern in most languages. First calculate, *then* when you have everything you need, print it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ok thanks for comment will try it right now!

Comment: @IngusGraholskis first you write ur php code & after that html part of table & in that where u want ur variables or  $taotal use them in HTML Table.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca and MohitKumar i posted answer of what i did please let me know if this is what you wanted me to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with @MohitKumar and @FedericoklezCulloca i tied to do it like this:

```
$table = '<table>';
$table .= '<thead>';
$table .= '<tr>';
$table .= '<th>product</th>';
$table .= '<th>value</th>';
$table .= '</tr>';
$table .= '</thead>';
$table .= '<tbody>';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT product, value FROM my_table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $table .= '<tr>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$row['product'].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$row['value'].'</td>';
    $table .= '</tr>';

    $abAmount += $row['value'];

}

$table .= '</tbody>';
$table .= '</table>';       

echo '<br>THAT VALUE HERE: '.$abAmount.'<br>';                  

echo $table;
```

And it did work!

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment by mistake. Yes, this is a good way to do this :)

Comment: @IngusGraholskis Yes , this is the approach i am telling. & finally u got ur excel by exporting as u want.